# Magento: all pages keep loading forever

Tags: php, magento

The problem is when I open any Magento page in browser, including /admin, it doesn't load properly and keeps loading forever. No files where changed - yesterday it was working, today it stopped working.

Can anyone recommend how to debug it? And what might be the reason for this?

There are no any errors in logs, php works fine, we tried rebooting server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

there wont be any errors unless you have low server resources, or maybe you have some content from external servers that probably down right now. first quick debug - open page in chrome and inspect element, you will see what slows your page. or you can check top, no IO problems, enough RAM, no processes running with >100% CPU?
rebooting server never fixes your problems. check if you have cache enabled.
not much information here to tell you exactly whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into this problem too. My Magneto 2 site (on Ubuntu 16.04) worked fine one day and then would continuously load the next. Cleaning the cache and deleting/rebuilding static files made it work briefly, but it would go back to not loading the pages within a few clicks... even the admin.

My fix happened to be that the disk was full. I didn't realize it until I went in command line and updated composer which kept giving me a disk full error.

I switched to the desktop on Ubuntu and ran a disk analyzer, which pinpointed exactly where all my space was being used.

```
gksudo baobab
```

I didn't have gksu installed, so I had to install it first by typing:

```
sudo apt install gksu
```

It turns out I had backups that had not been deleted. Large tar files that I no longer needed.

I hope this helps!

*Edited to include which OS I am using.*